# Stripe payment sheet error when paying with Google Pay in test environment

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

Our app uses Stripe to manage payments. Recently we enabled payments with Google Pay, we submitted the app for approval through the Google Pay & Wallet Console and the app has been approved.

The production app works well with Google Pay; the problem is that after the approval (I think the two things are related) the development app does not work anymore for Google Pay payments, while it worked until two days ago.

[image: Stripe payment sheet]

When I select Google Pay, a dialog appears with the following error:

> **Request Failed**
> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. [OR_BDF_27]

I looked for the error code (`OR_BDF_27`) but found nothing. Could someone help me to find the cause of the error?

This is how the Stripe payment sheet is configured:

```
stripePaymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
    paymentData.paymentIntentClientSecret,
    PaymentSheet.Configuration(
        merchantDisplayName = resources.getString(R.string.app_name),
        customer = PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
            paymentData.customerId,
            paymentData.ephemeralKeySecret,
        ),
        googlePay = PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration(
            environment = when (BuildConfig.IS_DEV) {
                true -> PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration.Environment.Test
                false -> PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration.Environment.Production
            },
            countryCode = OrderPaymentViewModel.PAYMENT_COUNTRY_CODE
        ),
        [...]
    ),
)
```

Comment: which `environment` are you passing when this error happens? Test or Production?

Comment: I'm passing Test. The Production environment has no problem after the app has been reviewed and approved in the Google Pay & Wallet console.

Comment: The problem has been solved by updating stripe dependency from 20.19.3 to 20.25.0